# Match a tag element inside a div with specific class in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to match the `h1`, `h2` and `p` tags inside a div with the class `apply_specific_styling`

The code is the following:

```
<div class="apply_specific_styling">
 <h1>Header 1</h1>
 <h2>Header 2</h2>
 <p>Some text here...</p>
</div>
```

How do you you achieve this with pure CSS. I google it with no success...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is how you could do it:

```
.apply_specific_styling h1,
.apply_specific_styling h2,
.apply_specific_styling p {
}
```

I suggest completing a [basic CSS tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started) though, because these selectors are very basic. We are very happy to help when you are stuck, but we cannot teach you CSS. This is not the right place for that.

Answer (score 1):

You could set CSS for those elements like this:

```
.apply_specific_styling h1,
.apply_specific_styling h2,
.apply_specific_styling p {
  /* your CSS here */
  color: yellow;
}
```

[View this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9rrKX/) for example.